# Rescale signal 1 by following signal 2 matlab

Tags: matlab

Let say I have

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ]
B = [0.01 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.07 0.04 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.04 0.03 0.02 0.01 0.011 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.04 0.01]
```

How can I rescale A follow maximum number of B.
The result should be

```
C = [0 0 0 0 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0 0 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0 0 0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` like so:

```
subs = cumsum([diff(A) > 0, 0]).*A + 1;  %//Similar to bwlabel if you have the image processing toolbox...
maximums = accumarray(subs(:), B(:), [], @max);
maximums(1) = 0;
C = maximums(subs)
```

Comment: +1 Neat! I was just working on a solution using ``accumarray`` as well. I think your result should be transposed though, such that it matches the desired dimension (row vector).

Comment: @danjoro do you mean the values of B where C equals 0.07? ``B(C==0.07)`` returns ``[0.0400    0.0500    0.0700    0.0400    0.0300]``

Comment: Yes correct. just want to test whether the result is correct or not. I have one question. Accually when I find back the answer I got total number of A is not same with C. For example if A = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ] , C i got [[0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0.07 0.07 0 0 0 0 0.04 0.04 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05 0.05 0.05 ] .  I want the total length is same. How can I get it.

Comment: @danjoro I get both `A` and `C` to be the same size i.e. `isequal(numel(A), numel(C))` returns `true`. I don't know what your `C` in that comment is or how you got it using my code...?

Comment: Yes same size. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want to do?

```
C = A*max(B)/max(A)
```